# Username/password authentication in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, wkwebview

When accessing the website in Safari, it'll ask for a username and password.

I'm trying to wrap a website into an app for reasons, however I can't get the username/password prompt to initiate.

This is the code I have as of now:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        let user = "*****"
        let password = "*****"
        let credential = URLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.forSession)
        challenge.sender?.use(credential, for: challenge)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myURL = URL(string: "http://WebsiteName")!
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

I expected there to be a username/login prompt box but it just remains as a 401 error with no prompt.

Comment: If it solved your problem consider it right answer thanks

Answer (score 1):

I Did something similar with webView years ago maybe this would be help

```
webView.delegate = self
        guard let orderID = orderID else { return }
        let urlString = GET_PAYMENT_PAGE + "\(orderID)" + "&comments=" + DataManager.shared.peymentComment
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!) else { return }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        let username = Authentication.auth.phoneNumber
        let password = Authentication.auth.token
        let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
        let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()


        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = JSON_HEAD
        request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Comment: Probably a stupid question but I have to ask - where exactly am I dropping this code?

Comment: Make a viewcontroller put a webView on it make the outlet and run in viewdidload